# Posting on a IOS device gives http exception in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

He guys im gettina a weird error in Xamarin(not the first time).. When i post data to my rest api using HttpClient and MultipartFormDataContent it works fine on IOS simulator however when i deploy on testflight and  use a device it keeps giving me a Http Exception error..Posting does work on my login and all my get requests..Any sugestions would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do your app has network usage permissions?

Comment: ya it does and all the relevent references

Comment: Is it only happening on your POSTs? Can you try add a simple GET code to test if it's happening on all HTTP Requests? Can you share the exact words of your HTTP error? Code?

Comment: For iOS make sure your endpoint is using https otherwise you will have to whitelist the url in the plist file. Here's a post that explain better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40299837/1771254

Comment: the URl im using is https.. The problem only occurs when i post a large amount of data i did set my timeout time to 2 min just for testing and still getting the same issue.

Comment: its also not even making it to the api...sometimes i do get back sucess but not all the time i think it might be something to do with the posting size

Comment: Weird thing is it works fine on a simulator with 100% success rate but on a device it works sometimes

Answer (score 0):

So the Main Problem was on the server side it was not making api because the max file size set by apache was 1 mb so updating that to 1 gb solved the problem